# Vertically-aligned text does not correctly align for dynamically added content

Tags: html, css

I saw many posts regarding how to set a child div to vertically align text in middle using line-height, but what if my text is appending dynamically?

I have a piece of code where the text keeps appending into a div.

I tried all the combinations :

1. Setting the div's display : table-cell
2. Setting vertical-align : middle
3. Setting line height [works but only when the text is static] - **the one that appends dynamically does not set text in the middle**.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janakshah89/9Twmk/) to my sample code.

All I need to do is append some text when a button is pressed. Also, the text should be vertically aligned.

```
<input type="button" id="press" value="press me"> 
<div id="containerForTable">
    <div id="R1">
    <div id="R0C1" class="floatLeft commonBorder"></div>
    <div id="R0C2" class="floatLeft commonBorder"></div>
    <div id="R0C3" class="floatLeft commonBorder"></div>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
    <div id="R2">
        <div id="R1C1" class="floatLeft commonBorder"></div>
    <div id="R1C2" class="floatLeft commonBorder"></div>
    <div id="R1C3" class="floatLeft commonBorder"></div>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

```
 #containerForTable{
   margin:60px 0px 0px 50px;    
 }
 .commonBorder{
border:1px solid black; 
text-align:center;
height:90px;
width:130px;
color:blue;
display:table-cell;
 }
 #R0C1,#R2C1,#R3C1,#R4C1{
border-top-left-radius:10px;
 }
 #R0C3,#R2C3,#R3C3,#R4C3{
border-top-right-radius:10px;
 }
 #R1C1,#R2C1,#R3C1,#R4C1{
border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
 }
 #R1C3,#R2C3,#R3C3,#R4C3{
border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
 }
 #R0C1,#R0C2,#R0C3{
text-align:center;
    height:30px; 
width:130px;    
 }
 #R1C1,#R2C1,#R3C1,#R4C1{
line-height: 75px;
 }


$('#R0C1').html('expression');
$('#R0C2').html('is same as');
$('#R0C3').html('is NOT same as');
$('#R1C1').html('p + 2 ');
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not how you're supposed to include code from the fiddle within your question. You're supposed to copy the code from the fiddle and paste it here, not just pick an arbitrary piece of text within your question and indent it like a code block.

Comment: @BoltClock: Well i am new to stackOverFlow and saw many users putting a fiddle link here. So i thought this is the right way of doing it. Also the code in the fiddle is my own code extracted from 1500 LOC's so that i can get an exact answer. Will take care next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `line-height` and `height` of your div are different, which is causing the text to become misaligned. That is, your `#R1C1, #R2C1, #R3C1, #R4C1` selector is applying a `line-height` of `75px`, while your `.commonBorder` selector is applying a `height` of `90px`.

Removing the `height: 90px` from your `.commentBorder` selector should fix the issue.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Twmk/1/)

Comment: +1 also, I don't know exactly what data the OP is marking up, but one shouldn't be afraid of using an actual table element if it's semantically correct to do so.

Comment: @Zhihao : This is working absolutly fine. Thanks for the help.
But i have 1 more doubt - If i have 5 entries in 2nd column, i want all the the columns of that row to have the same height as well as vertically alligned in the middle ?  Is there any way of doing it through css ??

Comment: @janakshah I'm not sure what you're asking. It seems like you mean 5 rows when you say "5 entries" in the 2nd column. You then mention "all the columns of that row to have the same height". What is "that row"? It also seems like you're suggesting a cell can have multiple columns, which is not possible.

Since this is a separate issue, I would recommend asking this in a new question and explaining it fully there. The comments is generally not a good place to ask for help on a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try, set vertical-align:middle;

```
.commonBorder{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: I tried this. But aint working. It is still coming in the top of the div.

Comment: it's almost 1500 Lines.
But even when i tried applying vertical-align middle, it isnt working.

Comment: how 1550 lines? You did  set height 90px only